# Simulate mouse in one window - C#

Tags: c#, mouse, simulation

I know this is possible since I've seen a few applications similar to what I'm developing use this, but I haven't the slightest clue on how to implement it. Basically, I need to create a mouse inside my applications form that works on its own. It should be able to click things on the form, even if the form is minimized.

So far my research has only brought up hundreds of people asking to simulate mouse events with the Windows API using mouse_event. This isn't what I need since that only clicks on the screen and not on a potentially hidden form.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If it's your own app, and the user isn't controlling this "mouse", then why do you need it? You could just call your buttonClick methods etc.

Comment: Because there aren't buttons that need to be pressed. There is a game that will be embedded into the form in a static place so that the mouse can map where it needs to click to do certain actions. Sometimes I wonder why people always ask what I'm developing and say "why are you doing this?".

Comment: Because context is helpful when answering a question. There's often a better way to do things.

Comment: Often people ask "Why are you doing this?" because what you are describing to the person sounds out of the ordinary, and if we can get a bigger picture we may be able to provide a better way of doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try sending WM_LBUTTONDOWN to your embedded game window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607.aspx

Comment: That was one of my previous ideas, but past tests didn't seem to work right. It'll be awhile before I can set up my project to accept that kind of test again, so I'll be messing around with it. I'll have to get back to this later unless there's a better answer.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer on what you're trying to accomplish... The proposal you have isn't going to work. Hidden windows don't receive mouse events. You need to come up with something else, and we can't make any suggestions until we know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why don't you just show the form, simulate a click, and quickly hide it back?

Comment: @CodyGray So far my current thoughts are I need to create a virtual desktop that can receive events as if it were on top without actually being on top. How I'd incorperate that into the form I haven't a clue, but I'm working on more research. I found the function `CreateDesktop` but I'm not 100% sure it's what I want. I'll be playing around with it though. @YoryeNathen that is not a good solution at all. That would interrupt user control on top of the fact of being potentially really buggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really emphasize on "mouse **simulation**". Autoit is a good choice. - *a freeware BASIC-like scripting language designed for automating the Windows GUI and general scripting*
Syntax is concise and easy to learn. The free autoit editor can generate exe, which you can execute it within your app.

**Example 1**: Simulate clicking at certain coordinates:

```
MouseClick ( "button" [, x, y [, clicks [, speed]]] )
```

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseClick.htm

**Example 2**: Simulate clicking a button

```
ControlClick ("My Window", "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:Finish; INSTANCE:2]")
```

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm

If you really want the mouse simulation within your app, I don't think there's any workaround not eventually sending mouse events via WinAPI.

Comment: No, this isn't what I want. I need to it to click on a hidden window. Anyway, I use AutoHotkey for this type of thing.

Answer (score -1):

SendMessage and PostMessage should work on hidden forms, use them with the WM_MOUSEXXXX codes and provide the mouse location in the wp or lp parameter, I forget which.